# High Sulfur and alkaline pH on Soil Test for Bermuda Lawn

Tags: lawn, soil-amendment

I did a My Soil Savvy test on my Bermuda lawn (Phoenix, AZ) and the Sulfur was 42.90ppm with a recommendation of 6-12.  The test also showed my pH at 7.14. Any ideas on how to reduce the sulfur and make the lawn more acidic(6.0-6.5)?

FYI there also slightly low levels on Nitrogen, Potassium, Iron and Zync.  Calium and Phosphorus are sightly high.

Answer (score 1):

Sulfur makes soils acidic. It is oxidized to sulfate . Gypsum ( calcium sulfate) is added to acidify soils. My guess is that you should put on some lawn fertilizer ( they are mostly nitrogen) and water it. Fertilizer with a little phosphate ( the middle number on the bag ) may help if none showed on your test. A pH of about 7 (neutral) sounds excellent.

Comment: Sadly, it's also high in Phosphorus (I'll add to FYI).  The pH recommendations I saw for Bermuda ran around 6.0 - 6.5.  Maybe I can try one of the Humic/Fulic acid products and a 10-0-2 fertilizer.